# What's the best IDE for C coding in Windows operation system?

Tags: windows, c++, ide, c

I'm newbie to C programming and I'm trying to choose the best IDE for C coding in Windows.

Based on my researches these are the best ones:

- Visual Studio
- Qt Creator
- Code::Blocks
- Eclipse
- NetBeans

So far I've figured out that *Visual Studio* is the best choice for Windows because it:

- is not that heavy
- supports adding new plugins and extensions
- has a user friendly UI
- has a toolkit to make GUIs

Anyway, I would like to know your practical experiences about the best IDE for working with C programming? Also a comparison between existing IDEs would be great.

Comment: maybe National Instruments?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's owl is another man's nightingale.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints. Further note that software comparison is off-topic here, see [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/69/185)

Comment: You have enough reputation elsewhere on the network - you should know better than asking a "what's the best thing?"-type question. Try reading [this](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23/c-ide-for-windows-with-a-rich-feature-set-code-completion-refactoring-etc) though.

Comment: I code embedded C and the industry standard is Eclipse

Comment: Use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) by Microsoft, can compile for gcc-7, python, java, and many more...

Comment: CLion by JetBrains (also Code::Blocks)

Comment: It is a matter of opinion, but consider [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) (to be used with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and with [git](https://git-scm.com/)...)

Answer (score 1):

[Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/product/development-tools) is only good if working with Qt. If you don´t want to be limited to Windows only, [Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/) is a good solution. [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) is good if you program not only in C but also Java, so you have 1 IDE for both languages. Eclipse is cross-platform as well.

Comment: Welcome!  If you can provide links to your recommendations, they will greatly improve your answer.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

Comment: Why links? He already knows the IDEs just asking which is the best.

Comment: SE is a community, and quality answers help everyone, not just the OP.

Comment: OK, links added